# Debian Stretch hangs at boot with "Please unlock disk xxx" error after upgrade from Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, luks

I upgraded my server from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch without any issue before the reboot. After rebooting, the server now hangs with the message "Please unlock disk xxx".

The disk in question is encrypted using LUKS, and there also are other encrypted disks in the system. However, these are NOT necessary to boot the system. In the past, I just SSHed into the system after a reboot, unlocked the disks manually (and then started the virtual machines which are stored on the encrypted disks).

I don't understand why unlocking now is attempted (mandatory?) during boot.

Is there a way to boot my system (so that I have SSH access) without entering LUKS credentials? I'd love to see an approach that I can tell to my "remote hands", possibly by fiddling with the kernel arguments in GRUB.

After getting into a (repair) SSH mode, how can I fix the issue for the next reboot?

Comment: Given that Debian uses systemd, take a look at the /etc/crypttab file: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html Among other things, it specifies which LUKS containers should be unlocked automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was my fault. PEBCAK. The system was configured with SWAP on a LVM LV on some LVM VG which is part of the encrypted disk. In other words, Debian correctly prompted me to decrypt the disk after the reboot.